# USDT Transaction Dropped & Replaced

Tags: transactions, etherscan, pending-transactions, usdt

While trying to send USDT to a wallet address, my transaction got dropped and replaced. I assumed that the transaction would go through if I just wait, but it seems that it got replaced and sent to a `0x00000000eddb52AAA642C5ce030A0405f4Db2A87`. This is the current hash: `0x15f15543943ec528af103587f7774812d751d0dafbc514852ade6c3b1e45a4e7` or https://etherscan.io/tx/0x15f15543943ec528af103587f7774812d751d0dafbc514852ade6c3b1e45a4e7.

This is the replaced hash: `0x15f15543943ec528af103587f7774812d751d0dafbc514852ade6c3b1e45a4e7` or https://etherscan.io/tx/0x15f15543943ec528af103587f7774812d751d0dafbc514852ade6c3b1e45a4e7.

If anyone could help me, that would be much appreciate because I really don't want to lose my funds. Thank you.

Comment: Happened with me as well on polygon chain. Seems like account hacked.

Comment: Is it possible to get it back though?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing gets lost when a transaction is dropped. It stays where it is,  if a replacement moves it then it ends up at the destination.
The USDT is at the address it was sent to, delivered with the replacement.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x00000000eddb52aaa642c5ce030a0405f4db2a87#tokentxns
[image]

Comment: Can I get it back? I did not send it to `0x00000000eddb52aaa642c5ce030a0405f4db2a87`, I wanted to send it to `0x4e6935aDd67CbD379DB90d99269e338f4EEd2E91`

Comment: No your address signed a direct transfer to move tokens from its own balance to the other account. It wasn't an approval scam so if you didn't do it someone has your private key. Which would mean they control your account, but you don't control the account they transferred the money to, so unless you can get the key from them and do what they did to you, there is no way.
Can see they have tried to take the last of the eth also, will likley go through once gas is cheaper. Protect your private key, don't share with anyone. Verify url's and people claiming to be support.

Answer (score 0):

Your wallet got hacked!
It happened on my side as well.
You can check my wallet history : bscscan.com/address/0x87ddb7e58f34496fbe6284c40252397f037a548b

I tried with another account on metamask and the funds on it got lost as well.
Another chrome account it happened same.

I recommend to install your OS again.